# How to put variable into string in .open("GET", "[...]")

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to put a variable into URL:

```
requeteAjax.open("GET", "../src/App/handler.php?id=");
```

For example, if I am on the event number 13, I want to have :

```
requeteAjax.open("GET", "../src/App/handler.php?id=13");
```

This is my form:

```php
<section class="chat">
    <div class = messages>
    </div>
    <div class="user-input">
        <form action="../src/App/handler.php?task=write" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name ="auteur" id="auteur" value="<?php echo $id_membre ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name ="id_event" id="id_event" value="<?php echo $id_event ?>">
            <input type="text" id="message" name="message">
            <button type="submit">Envoyer</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
<script src="../src/JS/chat.js"></script>
```

And this is a part of my JS code:

```
function getMessages(){
    const requeteAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    requeteAjax.open("GET", "../src/App/handler.php?id=");

    requeteAjax.onload = function(){
      const resultat = JSON.parse(requeteAjax.responseText);
      console.log(resultat);
      const html = resultat.reverse().map(function(mess){
        return `
          <div class="message">
            <span class="date">${mess.date.substring(5, 16)}</span>
            <span class="author">${mess.id_auteur}</span> : 
            <span class="content">${mess.message}</span>
          </div>
        `;
      }).join('');

      const messages = document.querySelector('.messages');

      messages.innerHTML = html;
      messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight;
    }
    requeteAjax.send();
  }
```

This is possible to send my variable `$id_event` of my .php to the js file?

After that, I need to put this variable into the URL...

Comment: Is this a follow up to the previous question or a duplicate?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. I don't know how to resolved my problem, so I found an other solution : change the url in ```requeteAjax.open("GET", "../src/App/handler.php?id=");``` but now I have an other problem

Answer (score 0):

In fact if I understand your problem well, you want to add a parameter in the url, then you can recover as a variable at the backend.For example if you work under php, you will recover it using the global variable in the following way, $ _GET ['name of the variable']. So, to do this,
I take your code but with the difference that, I want to add the necessary codes to illustrate how you must proceed to overcome your problem.

```
function getMessages(){

const requeteAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();

//Before
//requeteAjax.open("GET", "../src/App/handler.php?id=");
//After

 requeteAjax.open("GET", "../src/App/handler.php");

requeteAjax.onload = function(){
  const resultat = JSON.parse(requeteAjax.responseText);
  console.log(resultat);
  const html = resultat.reverse().map(function(mess){
    return `
      <div class="message">
        <span class="date">${mess.date.substring(5, 16)}</span>
        <span class="author">${mess.id_auteur}</span> : 
        <span class="content">${mess.message}</span>
      </div>
    `;
  }).join('');

  const messages = document.querySelector('.messages');

  messages.innerHTML = html;
  messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight;
}


    //before
    //requeteAjax.send();
    //after
    requeteAjax.send('id=3');
  }
```

Good luck!